# Interaction between reactable and Leaflet in shiny app (crosstalk, leafletproxy)

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet, reactable, crosstalk

My app has a leaflet object and a reactable object which interact via crosstalk.

When the user select a record from the table (using the checkbox), I want the app to add only the corresponding marker (using a different icon) and completely remove all others (not to show them shaded).

I am trying to achieve this using crosstalk and leafletproxy, but it seems the observeEvent is not working.

See below for reproducible example.
Thank you for any help.
António

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)

icon_x = makeIcon("https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/arrow-up-circle-fill.svg",
                  iconWidth = 16, iconHeight = 16)

icon_y = makeIcon("https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/arrow-up-circle-fill.svg",
                  iconWidth = 64, iconHeight = 64)

d <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  label = c("a","b","c"),
  long = c(-8,-8,-8.1),
  lat = c(39,39.1,39)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("texto"),
  reactableOutput("tbl"),
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  shared_d <- SharedData$new(d)
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(shared_d) %>%
      addTiles()  %>%
      setView(-8.05,39.05,11) %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, icon = icon_x)
  })
  
  output$tbl <- renderReactable({
  t<-  reactable(
      shared_d,
      onClick = "select",
      selection = "multiple",
      selectionId = "sel"
    )
    })
 
 d_new <- reactive({
   shared_d$data()[input$sel,]
  })   

  observeEvent(input$sel, {
  #  d_new <- d[d$id == input$sel,]
    output$texto <- renderText(print(input$sel))
       
    if (is.null(input$sel)){
      leafletProxy("map", data = d_new()) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, icon = icon_y)
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem using getReactableState instead of selectionID. And in the observeEvent, getReactableState must be converted to text.

Here's a working solution.

```
    library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)

icon_x = makeIcon("https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/arrow-up-circle-fill.svg",
                  iconWidth = 16, iconHeight = 16)

icon_y = makeIcon("https://icons.getbootstrap.com/assets/icons/arrow-up-circle-fill.svg",
                  iconWidth = 64, iconHeight = 64)

d <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  label = c("a","b","c"),
  long = c(-8,-8,-8.1),
  lat = c(39,39.1,39)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
#  textOutput("texto"),
  reactableOutput("tbl"),
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  shared_d <- SharedData$new(d)
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(shared_d) %>%
      addTiles()  %>%
      setView(-8.05,39.05,11)
  })
  
  output$tbl <- renderReactable({
  t<-  reactable(
      shared_d,
      onClick = "select",
      selection = "multiple",
      selectionId = "sel"
    )
    })

 d_new <- reactive({
   shared_d$data()[getReactableState("tbl","selected"),]
  })   

  observeEvent(as.character(getReactableState("tbl","selected")), {
  #  output$texto <- renderText(print(getReactableState("tbl","selected")))

    if (is.null(getReactableState("tbl","selected"))){
      leafletProxy("map", data = shared_d) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, icon = icon_x)
      }
    else{
      leafletProxy("map", data = d_new()) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, icon = icon_y)
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution @António! Is it possible to make it work the other way around, i.e., click on the point on the map to highlight the row in the table?